# Dynamically specify binding field

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically specify the field of an element to bind to an input value. The field name is specified by the creator of the html input, and the row (in an array of selectable rows) is specified by an html select.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">        

    <label for="ddlSelectionList">Select from list:</label>
    <select id="ddlSelectionList" ng-model="selectedRow" ng-options="row as row.name for row in selectionList" ></select>

    <div ng-repeat='text in texts'>
        <label for='txt{{text.id}}'>{{text.name}}</label>
        <input type="text" id='txt{{text.id}}' value='{{selectedRow.field1}}' />
    </div>

</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.selectionList=[
        {'id':5, 'name':'row 5', 'field1': 'row5field1', 'field2': 'row5field2', 'field3': 'row5field3'}, 
        {'id':9, 'name':'row 9', 'field1': 'row9field1', 'field2': 'row9field2', 'field3': 'row9field3'}];    

    $scope.selectedRow = $scope.selectionList[1];

    $scope.texts=[
        {'id': 453,
         'name': 'Input Text1',
         'listfieldname': 'field1'
        },
        {'id': 454,
         'name': 'Input Text2',
         'listfieldname': 'field2'
        },
        {'id': 455,
         'name': 'Input Text3',
         'listfieldname': 'field3'
        }
    ];


});
```

The [jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/9n3evrbq/2/). What I want to happen is bind the inputs to the field in the selectedRow as specified by the value of the text's listfieldname. Thus Input Text1 would show, at least initially, 'row9field1', Input Text2 would show 'row9field2' etc.

I'm not sure if this is even possible or how to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<input type="text" id='txt{{text.id}}' value='{{selectedRow.field1}}' />` to  `<input type="text" id='txt{{text.id}}' value='{{selectedRow[text.listfieldname]}}' />`

```
<div ng-repeat='text in texts'>
    <label for='txt{{text.id}}'>{{text.name}}</label>
    <input type="text" id='txt{{text.id}}' value='{{selectedRow[text.listfieldname]}}' />
</div>
```

**[updated](http://jsfiddle.net/9n3evrbq/4/)**

**Note:** you are actually binding static value **selectedRow.field1** , it always comes field1 value not field2,3 etc. So you can use for dynammic binding **selectedRow[text.listfieldname]**

Comment: perfect. Yeah, i knew that I was doing it statically.... but had tried {{selectedRow.{{text.listfieldname}}}} to no avail, so put it back to have something at least turn up for testing. Didn't know about the square brackets thing.